# wso2 governance registry resource upload timeout

Tags: upload, timeout, registry, wso2

I am trying to upload large wsdl file(with multiple schemas and endpoints). Everytime it takes around 2440 seconds before failing with timeout.
Is there a config or code change that can reduce this timeout period?

(I have not modified any of the default config yet)

Thanks,

Comment: Are you uploading multiple WSDLs as a ZIP file or uploading single WSDL with multiple schemas?
How many Schemas and Enpoints will get created with this upload?

Answer (score 0):

You can uncomment the `disableWSDLValidation`, and `disableSchemaValidation` properties in GREG_HOME/repository/conf/registry.xml.

Comment: I did that too. But still takes same amount of time.

Comment: The question I have is why every large wsdl times out after 2440 (+- 5 secs)? Is there a standard thread timeout or code config ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach the exception?

Comment: I see continuous logs of this db table lock exception -                  Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Timeout trying to lock table "REG_RESOURCE"; SQL statement:
SELECT DISTINCT REG_PATH_ID, REG_NAME FROM REG_RESOURCE WHERE (REG_RESOURCE.REG_TENANT_ID=?) AND  REG_MEDIA_TYPE=? [50200-140]
 at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.SQLQueryProcessor.executeQuery(SQLQueryProcessor.java:242)
 at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.queries.QueryProcessorManager.executeQuery(QueryProcessorManager.java:137)
 at org.wso2.carbon.regist

Comment: This seems to be a deadlock condition. And it has been reported earlier for some other use cases and seems to be fixed.https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-1164. Which version are you using? I hope you are trying one wsdl with multiple schemas and not a set of wsdl files zipped. One thing you can try is increasing the Datasource's maxwait by changing the config file at SERVER_HOME/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasource.xml  <maxWait>60000</maxWait> to a higher value. But if it is a deadlock it will not do any help. Could you please try this too.

Comment: Right. I also had come across that reported issue. I am using the latest registry 4.5.0. And I have tried increasing the timeout and also have tried adding MVCC=true to the db url. But that does not help. When I enable the sql stats logger, I see multiple db transactions which are started from quartz job. Can you help understanding that part of the system? I am not able to find that in the code? I mean, when I start upload, i see those quartz jobs being started too. I am trying to see if I can find the place where the transactions are deadlocked and if I can reduce the timeout for each upload.

Comment: On the side note, I have seen multiple issues reported regarding the REG_RESOURCE table lock, but everytime it was cloese by wso2 saying they could not reproduce it.

Comment: Could yo please create a JIRA here https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY. and also please add any steps logs or resources to reproduce the issue. It is best way to get this resolved quickly and more manageable way.